# How to show that there are non trivial solutions satisfying the conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with (b). I get a homogeneous system of equations, but got stuck with it. Tried to look up trigonometic identities with hyperbolic functions, but still don't get the answer.

The problem is the following one:

Consider the equation

$y^{(4)} - k^4y = 0$

where $k$ is a real constant.

(a) Show that $\cos(kx)$, $\sin(kx)$, $\cosh (kx)$, $\sinh (kx)$ are solutions if $k \neq 0$.

(b) Show that there are non-trivial solutions $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi'(0) = 0$, $\phi (1) = 0$, $\phi'(1) = 0$, if and only if $\cos(k) \cosh(k) = 1$ and $k \neq 0$

What I tried:

Once proved a), we have that $$\phi(x)=C_1\sin(kx)+C_2\cos(kx)+C_3\sinh(kx)+C_4\cosh(kx)$$
Using the condition  $\phi(0) = 0$, we have
$$\phi(0)=C_2+C_4=0$$

Now, $$\phi'(x)=C_1k\cos(kx)-C_2k\sin(kx)+C_3k\cosh(kx)+C_4k\sinh(kx)$$
Using the condition  $\phi'(0) = 0$, we have
$$\phi'(0)=C_1k+C_3k=0$$
If $k \neq 0$, then
$$C_1+C_3=0$$

Using the 3rd condition, we get
$$\phi(1)=C_1\sin(k)+C_2\cos(k)+C_3\sinh(k)+C_4\cosh(k)=0$$
Finally,
$$\phi'(1)=k(C_1\cos(k)-C_2\sin(k)+C_3\cosh(k)+C_4\sinh(k))=0$$

We have:

$C_2+C_4=0$   (1)

$C_1+C_3=0$   (2)

$C_1\sin(k)+C_2\cos(k)+C_3\sinh(k)+C_4\cosh(k)$   (3)

$C_1\cos(k)-C_2\sin(k)+C_3\cosh(k)+C_4\sinh(k)$   (4)

Then,
$$C_2=-C_4$$
$$C_1=-C_3$$
Using these two equalities in (3) and (4):

$-C_3\sin(k)-C_4\cos(k)+C_3\sinh(k)+C_4\cosh(k)=0$     (5)

$-C_3\cos(k)+C_4\sin(k)+C_3\cosh(k)+C_4\sinh(k)=0$     (6)

Multiplying (5) by $\cosh(k)$ and (6) by $-\sinh(k)$, then adding the new expressions, we have:

$-C_3\sin(k)\cosh(k)-C_4\cos(k)\cosh(k)+C_3\sinh(k)\cosh(k)+C_4\cosh^2(k)=0$

$C_3\cos(k)\sinh(k)-C_4\sin(k)\sinh(k)-C_3\cosh(k)\sinh(k)-C_4\sinh^2(k)=0$

$\Rightarrow$
$C_3(\cos(k)\sinh(k)-\sin(k)\cosh(k))-C_4(\sin(k)\sinh(k)+\cos(k)\cosh(k))+C_4(\cosh^2(k)-\sinh^2(k))=0$

Since $\cosh^2(k)-\sinh^2(k)=1$

$C_3(\cos(k)\sinh(k)-\sin(k)\cosh(k))-C_4(\sin(k)\sinh(k)+\cos(k)\cosh(k))+C_4=0$

And here is where I can't find something that can help.

Comment: Edit your question to show us what work you have done and where specifically you got stuck.

Comment: @TedShifrin Done.

Comment: Did you try writing (5) and (6) as a standard system of linear equations? What is the determinant of the $2\times 2$ coefficient matrix?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that... already got the answer, thank u soo so much.

Comment: Why don’t you post an answer? :)

Comment: I meant to put it as an official answer below. I will upvote it and you can (I think) accept the answer so the question will not stay on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the sistem $AX=0$, where $A$ is the matrix consisting of coefficients of (5) and (6):
\begin{pmatrix}
\sinh(k)-\sin(k) & \cosh(k)-\cos(k) \\
-\cos(k)+\cosh(k) & \sinh(k)+\sin(k) \\
\end{pmatrix}
Using trigonometric identities,

$\det(A)=-2+2\cos(k)\cosh(k)$.

If $\det(A)=0$, then the homogeneous system has more than just the trivial solution, so:
$$\det(A)=-2+2\cos(k)\cosh(k)=0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(k)\cosh(k)=1$$

Then the answer.